# Nav hover effect - Sliding the :hover background from one element to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've searched google and stackoverflow for this technique, but I'm at a loss.

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a class="active" href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Store</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

The active page would have a css background/class and I would like to slide that background to any element in the nav when I hover to it. Whenever the cursor over a nav element, it would create a hover state.

Thoughts?

Comment: I think you forgot to include what you've tried that isn't working

Comment: `Thoughts?` Many. Most unrelated to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/ky3akz9y/)?

Just whipped it up in a couple mins but I think it's close enough

**JS**

```
$("#navMenuBackground").height = $(".navItems").outerHeight();

$(".navItems").mouseover(function () {
    $("#slideMe").stop();
    var width = $(this).outerWidth();
    var height = $(this).outerHeight();
    var left = $(this).position().left;
    var top = $(this).position().top;
    $("#slideMe").animate({
        left: left,
        top: top,
        width: width,
        height: height
    }, 200);
});
```